# How to append data to an existing Excel file based on the input?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, selenium, scrapy

I am currently writing a Scrapy Webcrawler that is meant to extract data from a site's page and append those data to an existing excel(**".tmp.xlsx"**) file. The file comes with prepopulated column headers like **"name", "country", "state", "zip code", "address", "phone number"**. The sites i will be scraping most times wont have data to populate all columns. Some can have data for just **"country", "state", "zip code" and "phone number"**..
I need help setting up my **pipelines.py** in a way whereby i will be appending to the file based on the type of data i get from the site im crawling..

Answer (score 0):

One option (which may not be what you are looking for) is to just append the data to a CSV (using Scrapy's builtin `CsvItemExporter`). Then in the `close_spider` method, convert it to an excel file (using e.g., `pandas`).

Answer (score 0):

this code maybe help you
put this in setting.py

```
FEED_FORMAT = 'csv'  #format
FEED_URI =  "tmp.csv" #the path of output
```

```
# put this in the last of spider 
    def close(self, reason):
        df=pd.read_csv("tmp.csv")
        df.to_excel("tmp.xlsx",index=False) #to do not  make index
```

If you need any help do not hesitate to ask